# How to pass the scenario id as a parameter in Workshop?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop, foundry-scenarios

I have a workshop module which is handled by scenarios. I am trying to pass that scenario id so that the Ontology action can create/edit the details of the stored scenario dataset, but i m not getting where i can get this id from. I know this is very little information but i just need the id to be passed and i cannot pass it from the module, i can only apply to scenario but i need the attributes to be stored in the writeback dataset. If we use "apply to scenario" this doesn't get stored.

Please help

Comment: I don't know how to do it, just linking a tutorial on scenarios here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mfxcINKc7o in case it helps other folks

Answer (score 0):

To access save the scenario_id you can configure the commit action in the Ontology Manager App to select this property. Now, depending on where you want to save this scenario_id, you can “Add a new rule” that takes the scenario_id as a parameter and writes it as a new entry to your object type, or modifies an existing entry in your dataset.

For example, I have object type “Passenger” and i’m using a scenario to modify a property called “number of flights”. Now every time someone applies the scenario, i want to see in the uuid of the scenario as one of the Passenger’s object properties. In this case, my commit action will have a rule that modifies the Passenger Object and puts the Scenario uuid in the new property called “Modified by Scenario”.